# [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: element.circleProgress is not a function"

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js

I got this problem:

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: element.circleProgress
> is not a function"

```
animateCircle(element, percents, oldPortion) {
                let portion = percents / 100; // convert from percents
                portion -= Math.min(portion * 0.02, 0.01); // prevent user from confusion by cursor

                element.circleProgress({
                    'value': portion,
                    'animationStartValue': oldPortion,
                });
                element.circleProgress();
            },
            initCircle() {
                const vm = this;
                const element = $(this.$refs.circleProgress);

                element.circleProgress({
                    animation: {
                        duration: 1100,
                        easing: 'circleProgressEasing',
                    },
                    size: 247,
                    thickness: 20,
                    startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
                    emptyFill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                    fill: {
                        image: 'img/upgrade/circle-progress.png',
                    },
                }).on('circle-animation-progress', function (event, progress, stepValue) {
                    if (vm.upgradeCircle.progressFn) {
                        vm.upgradeCircle.progressFn(event, progress, stepValue);
                    }
                }).on('circle-animation-end', function () {
                    vm.upgradeCircle.active = false;
                });

                this.upgradeCircle.element = element;
                this.upgradeCircle.canvas = $(element.circleProgress('widget'));
            }
        },
```

I don't know why it is in my index.vue I have jquery installed :

```
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.0-beta.14/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/all.css">
            <link href="/css/wnoty.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}?v={{time()}}">
    
    
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.0-beta.14/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.0-beta.14"></script>
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
       <script src="/dash/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/wnoty.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.4/clipboard.min.js"></script>

var pluginName = 'roulette';
            $.fn[pluginName] = function (method, options) {
                return this.each(function () {
                    var self = $(this);
                    var roulette = self.data('plugin_' + pluginName);
                    if (roulette && roulette[method]) {
                        if (roulette[method]) {
                            roulette[method](options);
                        } else {
                            console && console.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.roulette');}
                    } else {
                        roulette = new Roulette(method);
                        roulette.init(self, method);
                        $(this).data('plugin_' + pluginName, roulette);
                    }
                });
            }
        })(jQuery);
```

I don't know why it tells me that it is not a function when I am
calling jquery from the index. I don't know if I have to import it
directly into the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error 'element.circleProgress is not a function' means that the jquery plugin circleProgress is not available at the moment.

This may be caused by if you load jquery multiple times on a page. Looking at your code I get the idea that you are loading jquery 2 times: The first time from code.jquery.com and the second time from /dash/js/jquery.min.js

```html
<!-- load jquery for the first time: -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<!-- register plugin circle-progress -->
<script src="dist/circle-progress.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.0-beta.14"></script>
<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load jquery a second time? -->
<script src="/dash/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If that is the case you should decide which jquery you require and make sure you only load that once. The second time you load jquery all previously registered plugins are cleared/forgotten and that may cause the error 'element.circleProgress is not a function', which means that the circleProgress plugin is not available.